# Why is multiple inheritance not the main purpose of interfaces?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

My teacher kept saying that interfaces are not there so one could use them as a way to achieve multiple inheritance in c#.

Why is that? What are they for then? Noone could explain this to me easily yet, I'm so confused.

I read a few articles and books that described interfaces and it seems that all of them are suggesting to use interfaces as a workaround to implement multiple inheritance..

Comment: Inheritance normally makes you richer.  Interfaces only ever make you poorer, they make you work harder to implement them.

Comment: Given that interfaces contain no implementations, they surely can't be used to give you *inheritance* - there's nothing to inherit. There's only the contract that you need to actually implement in a class that claims to implement the given interface. That's why we use the two words in the first place - "inherits" vs "implements".

Comment: Interfaces allow you enforce a contract upon an object.  That object will have **at least** the interface "functionality" allowing you to perform some kind of action against it.  The object does not necessarily have to satisfy the "is a" condition, which is usually what is required of inheritance.  An object can implement as many interfaces as it wants.

Comment: At the risk of sounding stupid, why don't you ask your teacher about  things they say that you don't understand? Most teachers I know, rather than thinking less of you for "not getting it", would be delighted to get questions from inquisitive students that allow them to explain things further.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you don't sound stupid at all! In fact, I'm the stupid one here. I actually asked him and he gave me a rather quick answer but I still didn't get it. I was too ashamed to ask again.

Comment: Don't be. Not getting it is sort of the whole job of a student, that's why you are a student. Never be ashamed of not understanding something for any reason other than not having put in the effort to understand it. If you're afraid of wasting the time of the rest of the class, or your teacher clearly has no more time right then, just try to get a private audience, or send a mail. Of course asking Stack Overflow isn't wrong either, but nothing beats an available teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a statically typed language, or when using static typing in a language that has both dynamic and static typing (such as C#), then inheritance consists of two pieces.  The interface, and the implementation.  The interface is a contract that says that it will fulfill a specific set of methods or properties.  The implementation is the code that actually does it.  Code *implements* an interface.

Interfaces are used to guarantee that an object implements specific contracts.  This can be a single contract, or multiple ones.  This is not multiple inheritance, which inherits both the interface and the implementation.

Yes, some people try to simulate multiple inheritance with multiple interfaces, but that's not its purpose, and that simulation is very poor anyways.

Multiple interfaces says that an object supports multiple contracts.  Multiple inheritance says that an object re-uses multiple implementations.  Again, inheritance requires both interface and implementation.  Interface implementation is just the interface.

Comment: My teacher just said the first paragraph. Now it seems A LOT more logical to me. Thank you @Erik !

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces form a contract (they say what an object can do), but don't provide implementation.

Why bother? Defining the contract is extra work, why not just create a class?

For example, let's say you want to develop a drawing app. You may come up with few objects like Circle, Triangle, Square, etc. then you start adding methods and add something like `Draw()`. That is something you could add to the interface that all shapes implement. In C#, by convention it would be named something like `IDrawable`.

But why not a class?

Let's imagine you are extending the app and adding a support for grouping shapes, to create more complex patterns. The groups can also be drawn, so they also have `Draw()` method. Now, if you only want to draw the "thing", you do not need to know if it is a shape or a group, or something else you haven't invented yet.

But why not a class?

Because there could be more capabilities, like `Move()`, `Serialize()`, etc, and C# doesn't allow you to inherit from multiple classes.

Why not?

It is not a technical limitation, but a choice made by C# language designers. Some languages, like C++ allow it, but it brings few technical problems, most famously the [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance). It also makes the compiler more complicated and it's been decided [it is not worth it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/07/why-doesnt-c-support-multiple-inheritance/). It also